# Can't resolve method setAction() error in Snackbar

Tags: android, snackbar

I made a function of Snackbar :

```
 void openSnackbar(String title){
            Snackbar
                    .make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                            title,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("",this)
                    .show();
    }
```

But inside `seAction()` method second perameter as `this`  giving error `you can't resolve method setAction(java.util.String,package.....)`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [official javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#setAction(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.view.View.OnClickListener)).

```
  setAction (CharSequence text, View.OnClickListener listener)

  Parameters:
    text        Text to display
    listener    callback to be invoked when the action is clicked
```

You can use something like this:

```
  Snackbar
       .make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
             title,
             Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
       .setAction("", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Your code
                }
            })
       .show();
```

Otherwise you can use:

```
  Snackbar
       .make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
             title,
             Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
       .setAction("", myOnClickListener)
       .show();

myOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Your code
                    }
                };
```

If you would like to use

```
.setAction("",this)
```

your class have to implement the [View.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) interface.

Answer (score 2):

> But inside seAction() method second perameter as this giving error you
>   can't resolve method setAction(java.util.String,package.....)

the second parameter of `setAction` is an instance of a class that implements `View.OnClickListener`. If the compiler is complaining about it , it is because your class is not implementing that interface.